# Excel Count cells with number if certain conditions are met

Tags: excel, count, conditional-statements

I want to find the percent of cells in the column NO2 (for example) that contain a number, only considering cells that fall in a certain month during a certain hour - so for example, how many cells contain numbers in the NO2 column during hour one during each day in January.

I've been trying to do `1 - COUNTIF(condition,"*")/COUNTA(condition)`, but I'm having trouble writing up the condition part.

Condition (considering three months). It gives me a $VALUE! error if I try to put this into `COUNTIF`

```
IF($C$1:$C$8985="January",
IF($B$1:$B$8985="1:00",$E$1:$E$8985,""),
IF($C$1:$C$8985="February",
IF($B$1:$B$8985="1:00",'$E$1:$E$8985,""),
IF($C$1:$C$8985="December,
IF($B$1:$B$8985="1:00",$E$1:$E$8985,"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `=SUMPRODUCT()`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="January"), --(B:B=TIMEVALUE("1:00")), --(ISNUMBER(C:C)))
```

Where you'd replace:

- `A:A` with your month column
- `B:B` with your time column
- `C:C` with your NO2 column

### Adding in 'OR Logic'

If you are wanting to use **OR logic**, you can simply "add" the criteria to look like
`--((A:A="January")+(A:A="February"))`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((A:A="January")+(A:A="February")), --(B:B=TIMEVALUE("1:00")), 
    --(ISNUMBER(C:C)))
```

So this says Column A can *either be* `January` **OR** `February`, **and** Column B has a time value of `1:00`, **and** column C is a numeric value.

---

This essentially creates three arrays - 1 for each of your criteria. It would look something like this:

```
{"January", "January", "January", "February"}  
{"1:00 AM", "1:00 AM", "2:00 AM", "1:00 AM" }  
{      1.0,       1.3,    "text",         4 }
```

It converts these into True/False

```
{True, True, True, True}
{True, True,False, True}
{True, True,False, True}
 ^^^^  ^^^^        ^^^^     << Counts the number where ALL are 'True'
```

When each of the 'indexes' all return true, it is added into your function.

> *If these arrays do not have the same length, then your `SUMPRODUCT()` function will return an error.*
>
> ```
> {True, True, True, True}
> {True, True,False, True}
> {True, True,False}
>  ^^^^  ^^^^        *ERR    << Returns error as the last array was smaller
> ```

Comment: Are the `--` placeholders or do they mean something?

Comment: They just convert the Boolean `True/False` to a number. You could also multiply the product by `*1` - such as `(A:A="January")*1`. Think about it multiplying it by -1, twice (as in if you only did it once it would return a negative result).

Comment: So `A:A="January"` by itself would return `True`. When you add the `--()`, it converts it to a numerical value.

Comment: The logic makes sense, but it's giving me either 0 or #VALUE! error still. I gave it the entire column as an input for each condition so they should be all the same size.

Comment: Hmm. Do you mind posting an example of your formula?

Comment: I posted a section of what I'm working on here with the formula https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m4r4aofhe-FigSX1KW1juANo3X_MFLls

Comment: @shizishan I looked at your worksheet - everything is set up correctly. I found your problem is that in your **Time Column**, It's not **Exactly** `1:00:00 AM`. If you typed over that with `1:00` it will add it. Idk where you got this time from, but it's off by a very very small decimal point, yet is still rounding to `1:00 AM`.